# Somente Letras Maiúsculas e Minúsculas e acentos em expressões regulares

Tags: php, regex, validação, validator

Como criar uma expressão regular da maneira certa onde aceite somente letras maiúsculas e minúsculas, junto com acentos?

Isto é para validar uma `string` de nome, eu criei da seguinte maneira:

```
$String  = preg_replace("/([^a-zà-úA-ZÀ-Ú ])/", "", $String);
```

Funciona perfeitamente mas com um porém, pois vem junto os caracteres: **äåæËÎÏÐðÑ×÷ØÝÞß**

Existe outra maneira de criar sem que esses caracteres venham junto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode incluir uma condicional `|` seguida dos caracteres entre `[]` que você quer incluir na pesquisa:

```
/([^a-zà-úA-ZÀ-Ú ]|[äåæËÎÏÐðÑ×÷ØÝÞß])/
```

Se tiver problemas com acentuação no `preg_replace`, insira a *flag* `u` (Unicode):

```
/([^a-zà-úA-ZÀ-Ú ]|[äåæËÎÏÐðÑ×÷ØÝÞß])/u
```

**[Ideone](https://ideone.com/PBlSPq)**

**[RegExr](https://regexr.com/3iejt)**